# Invalid Character Error - XML format in java

Tags: java, xml, character

I have a .txt file:

```
Seven Pounds
Drama
13 martie 2009
8
tt0814314
/
Source Code
Mystery SF Thriller
1 aprilie 2011
8
tt0945513
/
V for Vendetta
Action Drama Thriller
16 martie 2006
8
tt0434409
/
Braveheart
Action Biography Drama
24 mai 1995
9
tt0112573
/
Se7en
Drama Mystery Thriller
22 septembrie 1995
9
tt0114369
/
```

And what I'm trying to do is the following: read all from file in a `List<List<String>> L` then write them into a XML format. The problem is that I get and INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR message, even though I had replaced space characters. The error message is this:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML              character is specified. 
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(CoreDocumentImpl.java:622)
at pa.tema5ex1.Tree.CreeazaRaportXML(Tree.java:246)
at pa.tema5ex1.PATema5Ex1.main(PATema5Ex1.java:22)
```

and the code I've been doing by now is the following:

```
public void CreeazaRaportXML()
{
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();


        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("ColectieDeFilme");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        for (int i = 0; i < colectieFilme.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colectieFilme.size(); j++)
            {
                String current = colectieFilme.get(i).get(j).replaceAll(" ", "").replace("\n", "");
                System.out.println("current -> " + current);
                Element dateFilmCurent = doc.createElement(current);
                rootElement.appendChild(dateFilmCurent);     
            }

        }

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\miTzuliK\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\[PA]Tema5Ex1\\RaportXML.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        // Output to console for testing
        StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I believe it's a bit wrong approach since you are using data as tag name. it would be more correct to create xml structure like

```
<film>
  <name>Seven Pounds</name>
  ...
  <id>tt0434409</id>
</film>
```

In this case you control structure and avoid unexpected not allowed characters in XML tag name

2) If you still want to use current approach try to trim string st the end , maybe there is specific line separator.

3) It's probably not correct usage of second for loop. You iterate by size on initial List which if wrong. Think should be like

```
for (int i = 0; i < colectieFilme.size(); i++) {
  List<String> filmStrings = colectieFilme.get(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < filmStrings.size(); j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```